# I want to SELECT one column in three diferend ways to separate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with few columns but I am interested in two of them:

1. name
2. type - it can be one of tree values: 1, 2, 3

All I want to create is a table where in first column I will SELECT value from column name where type = 1, in second column value from column name where type = 2, in last column value from column name where type = 3

I tried to create a subquery (I want to do it via CTE) but I got an error about the subquery returns more than 1 value. I tried something with case clause but its not working anyway. I was thinking about UNION it but I am not sure.
This is how the basic table looks like:

```
SELECT name, type
FROM table1
```

Table:

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | 1 |
| Product2 | 2 |
| Product3 | 1 |
| Product4 | 3 |

And how I want to see SELECT it:

| Product with type 1 | Product with type 2 | Product with type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | Product9 | Product33 |
| Product5 | Product11 | Product41 |
| Product3 | Product17 | Product22 |
| Product7 | Product20 | Product23 |

I just don't know how to show values with where type = 1 as one column, type = 2 as second column and type =3 as third.

Comment: Can you provide us sample data and expected output?

Comment: @PauloFernando added in question

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Azure SQL Edge or SyBase, please [edit] your question to correct the tags.

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL Server that's right nothing more

Comment: @ninjaloot777 - If you get in the habit of providing "Readily Consumable" data, like I did in the answer I posted, along with the other things folks asked you previously (which you did), you'll get code answers much more quickly and people won't have reason to vote your question down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL;

```
SELECT
  IF(type=1, name, NULL) as "Product with type 1",
  IF(type=2, name, NULL) as "Product with type 2",
  IF(type=3, name, NULL) as "Product with type 3"
FROM table1
```

For T-SQL;

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN type=1 THEN name ELSE NULL END as "Product with type 1",
  CASE WHEN type=2 THEN name ELSE NULL END as "Product with type 2",
  CASE WHEN type=3 THEN name ELSE NULL END as "Product with type 3"
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following handles the problems of offset columns due to nulls and unequal columns.

```
--===== Create some Readily Consumable Test Data.
     -- This is NOT a part of the solution.
     -- We're just creating test data here.
     -- Changed one "type" to show how unequal columns are handled.
 SELECT *
   INTO #table1
   FROM (VALUES
         ('Product1' ,1)
        ,('Product3' ,1)
        ,('Product5' ,1)
        ,('Product7' ,1)
        ,('Product9' ,2)
        ,('Product11',2)
        ,('Product17',2)
        ,('Product20',2)
        ,('Product22',2) --Changed type here
        ,('Product23',3)
        ,('Product33',3)
        ,('Product41',3)
        )v(name,type)
;
--===== Solve the problem with a classic CROSSTAB.
     -- "Normal" sort assumed. If you want 2 part alpha-numeric sort, 
     -- then post back in the comments on this post.
   WITH cteEnumerate AS
(
 SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY name)
   FROM #Table1
)
 SELECT  [Product with Type 1] = MAX(IIF(type = 1,name,''))
        ,[Product with Type 2] = MAX(IIF(type = 2,name,''))
        ,[Product with Type 3] = MAX(IIF(type = 3,name,''))
   FROM cteEnumerate
  GROUP BY RowNum
;
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way is using case to separate the columns according to the type, but then you will have to handle the nulls that will remain in the cells

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN  name ELSE NULL END
    , CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN name ELSE NULL END
    , CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN name ELSE NULL END
FROM table1
enter code here
```

| Product with type 1 | Product with type 2 | Product with type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | Product9 | NULL |
| NULL | Product11 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | Product33 |

Another way is to use pivot, only there you will not be able to show duplicate Names, but you will be able to show the grid as in the example

```
SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] FROM table1 PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR type IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS P
```

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | Producto 2 | Producto 3 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: I tried this and it's working too. But I don't know if it's good for optimization with higher amount of types. Of course + 1 for working sample

Comment: Another way is to use pivot, only there you will not be able to show duplicate Names, but you will be able to show the grid as in the example

SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM table1
PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR type IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS P